# Take me to a page a certain fraction of the time.

Tags: html, squarespace

How would I create a button that would take me to a certain page on my site 1/4th of the time while bringing me to a second page on my site 3/4th's of the time? Ideally it would pick a random integer between 1-4, if 1 is picked it would go to the first page, of 2, 3, or 4 is picked it would go to the second page. What would the HTML code look like if I were to throw a line or two of code into a website creator that creates a button?

Comment: You will need Javascript for that.

Comment: Dang. No other way around it?

Comment: Not with pure HTML

Comment: Could you share an example of what it would look like with Java?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following full HTML example, I've tried to make it as simple as possible -

You will just need to add the javascript at the bottom of your page, and change the ID of submitBtn in the script to whatever the ID of the button on your existing page.

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
 <button id='submitBtn'>Submit</button>
</body>

<script>
 //get the button by the ID, your ID may differ
 var submitBtn = document.getElementById('submitBtn');
 
 //define the action you want to take when the button is clicked
 submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  //set the min and max values for the random number to be between
  var maximum = 4;
  var minimum = 1;
  //get the random number
  var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;
  
  //do your logic on the random number
  if(randomnumber == 1){
   window.location.href = 'http://urlwhennumberis1.com';
  }
  else{
   window.location.href = 'http://urlforanyothernumber.com';
  }
 });

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you Dan